# How to get XML node attribute values in Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, attributes

I have an XML file and I have to retrieve all its attributes.

How to achieve that *without knowing their names and values?*

My XML file structure looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEST0>
    <TEST1>
        <TEST2>
            <TEST3 name="myname1" value="myvalue1" />
            <TEST3 name="myname2" custVal="myvalue2" />
        </TEST2>
    </TEST1>
    <TEST4>
      <TEST5 name="myname3" custVal="myvalue3"/>
    </TEST4>
</TEST0>
```

This is what I tried:

```
 [System.Xml.XmlDocument] $xmlContent = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument;
    $file = resolve-path('./myxml.xml');
    $xmlContent.load($file)
    $nodelist = $xmlContent.selectnodes("//*"); 

    foreach ($node in $nodelist) {
       Write-Host $node.Name " = " $node.Value
    }
```

This is the **expected** result:

```
myname1 = myvalue1
myname2 = myvalue2
myname3 = myvalue3
```

But this is **my result**:

```
myname1 = myvalue1
myname2 = 
myname3 =
```

**THE PROBLEM:** It searches for attribute named value, but not all my attributes are named like this, some of them are custom and I don't know the names. What can i do in this case?

**UPDATE:** To get the *actual* attributes names and values just add **.Attribues** in the loop:

```
 foreach ($node in $nodelist) {
       Write-Host $node.Name " = " $node.Value
    }
```

**This returns:**

```
name = myname1 
value = myvalue1
name = myname2 
custVal = myvalue2
name = myname3 
custVal = myvalue3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
[xml]$xmlContent = Get-Content -Path (Resolve-Path -Path './myxml.xml') -Raw

$nodelist = $xmlContent.SelectNodes("//*[@name]")

foreach ($node in $nodelist) {
    Write-Host ('{0} = {1}' -f $node.Name, $node.Attributes[1].'#text')
}
```

Result:

> ```
> myname1 = myvalue1
> myname2 = myvalue2
> myname3 = myvalue3
> ```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! :) . I also just realised If i need to get the actual attribute name I can use ($node in $nodelist.Attributes) { Write-Host $node.Name " = " $node.Value } This returns: `name=myname1 value=myvalue1
name=myname2 custVal=myvalue2`